# extract the numbers diference betwin tow string

Tags: php, string

I have `string1 = "1234567891011121314151617181920"`
and I have `string2 = "123"`

How can I extract `string3` to equal `"4567891011121314151617181920"` starting from `string1` and `string2` in PHP?

I have try this but no results

```
foreach($dejasprise as $k=>$v){
    $prises = $v;
    echo $prises."<br />";
    foreach($options as $key=>$value ){
        if($value == $prises){
            echo "non</br>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo $value."<br />";   
        }
    }
```

Comment: looks like your question makes no sense. Please try to make it clearer. You also miss the closing bracket.

Comment: see , i have 2 strings ok !! 
the 1st  for example = "12345"
the 2nd for example = "123"
i want to make 3rd string = "45"

Comment: `preg_match('/^'.preg_quote( $string1 ).'(.+)$/', $string2, $string3 )` $string3 will be an array so you need `$string3[1]` - essentially this https://regex101.com/r/fO7uE2/1 - but only if string1 is the start of string2

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to trim string2 from string1, and the end result is string3. Try `$string3 = str_replace($string2,"",$string1)`

Comment: what if 123 is in the string latter?  Or 2x, then you replace them both, it's not in this case, but that is an assumption I would not make.

Comment: For this particular case, then, `$string3 = str_replace($string2,"",$string1,1)`

Comment: Hi 
the solution of @pioneer work  perfectly but only if the 1st number of the 1st string mutch the number of 2end string for exemple , if i have :

$var1 = 1234
$var2 = 123456
here the $var3 = str_replace($var1 ,"",$var2 ) wille be "56"

But if 
$var1 = 36
$var2 = 123456
the $var3 = str_replace($var1 ,"",$var2 ) wille be "123456"

here is my PHP code

Comment: include("../scripts/session.php");  
if(isset($_POST["raionid"]) && is_numeric($_POST["raionid"])){
include("../scripts/connexion.php");
$raionid = $_POST["raionid"];
$SQLFindRaionPlacement = "SELECT * FROM raion WHERE raion_id = ?";
$STMTFindRaionPlacement = $connect->stmt_init();
if(!$STMTFindRaionPlacement->prepare($SQLFindRaionPlacement)){
}

Comment: else {
$STMTFindRaionPlacement->bind_param("s", $raionid);
$STMTFindRaionPlacement->execute();
$ResultFindRaionPlacement =  $STMTFindRaionPlacement->get_result();
$ArrayFindRaionPlacement = $ResultFindRaionPlacement->fetch_array();
$Emplacementses =  $ArrayFindRaionPlacement["raion_nbplaces"];
$RaionNom = $ArrayFindRaionPlacement["raion_nom"];
$SQLSelectraionbon = "SELECT * FROM raion_bon WHERE raion_name =  ?";
$STMTSelectraionbon = $connect->stmt_init();
if(!$STMTSelectraionbon->prepare($SQLSelectraionbon)){
}

Comment: else {
$STMTSelectraionbon->bind_param("s" , $RaionNom );
$STMTSelectraionbon->execute();
$ResultSelectraionbon = $STMTSelectraionbon->get_result();
while( $ArraySelectraionbon = $ResultSelectraionbon->fetch_array()){
$Emplacement .= $ArraySelectraionbon["place_prise"].".";
}
for($i = 1 ; $i <= $Emplacementses; $i++){
$emplacementdispo .=  $i.".";
}
$exmplacement = str_ireplace($Emplacement,"",$emplacementdispo); 
echo $Emplacement."<br />"; 
echo $emplacementdispo."<br />" ;
echo $exmplacement."<br />" ;

Comment: $exmplacement = explode(".",$exmplacement );
foreach($exmplacement as $k=>$v){
$Version = $v;
echo '<option  value="'.$Version.'">'.$Version.'</option>';
}
}
}
}